# ScrollView not scrolling with full Size app

Tags: android

So I have some difficult trying to make my app show fullscreen (without that damn actionBar).

I achieved it by doing this on my **mainActivity.java**:

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

If I comment the line above, the scroll works again, but then the background image start to move everytime I open/close the keyboard.

The problem now is that the ScrollView is no longer scrolling the elements when I open the keyboard and it hides the button.

#### CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ghaleon.hqsm.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/bg2"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:fillViewport="true"
    >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/transp_white_rect"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Faça seu Cadastro"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="E mostre ao mundo o seu talento"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_white"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_person_pin"
                android:id="@+id/userEmail"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

                />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_white"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock_outline"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/userPassword"
            />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:hint="Confirm Password"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_white"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock_outline"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:id="@+id/userConfirmPassword"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="REGISTER"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:background="@drawable/register_button"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How to keep the app NOT SHOWING the actionBar but also allow the scrollView to scroll?

ScreenShot: 
As you guy can see, I have a button below those `AutoCompleteTextView`. I can't scroll down to click the button.
[image]

#### MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.biruleibe.hqsm">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Example without fullscreen: (The purple little bar shows up with clock/battery/etc... AND the background image MOVES whenever I open/close the keyboard). But the scroll works.

[image]

Comment: You can set this in your theme in styles.<style name="themex" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></style>

Comment: I already have this: `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`. It removed the bar with the `AppName` variable. But I still have a small bar with different color (a bar that holds the clock/battery/wifi signal/ and all those top icons).

Comment: For Full screen you should add this <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item> in your style.

Comment: I commented my code on java class, added yours to style. It's the same thing: FullScreen working but can't scroll =\

Comment: can you post a screenshot of whats happening.

Comment: @AmanVerma Done!

Comment: Have you tried setting the height of the scroll view to match_parent

Comment: Yes ! Even with the full height the scroll does not work =(

Comment: what have you set in your manifest in the activity ? android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: @AmanVerma Just updated with manifest and one more example. I can change the color of that purple bar to black so would be hard to notice. But the background image still moves, is it normal if the image is big?  ;s

Comment: What the actual size of the image??

Comment: @AmanVerma It's 1920x1080

Comment: It is not recommended to use high quality images. What you can do is you can add image to your drawable for every type of screen available like ldpi, mdpi, xdpi and hdpi and etc...

Comment: did you check the answer??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you should set your style as -

```
<style name="themex" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

// your style
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>

</style>
```

And in Android Manifest you should define windowsoftinputmode as

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
            />
```

And finally the Layout. Its a hack and i have done it so many time without any issues.

Add an empty textview below you Button And set MarginTop to around - 300dp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ghaleon.hqsm.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/bg2"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:fillViewport="true"
    >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/transp_white_rect"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Faça seu Cadastro"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="E mostre ao mundo o seu talento"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_white"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_person_pin"
                android:id="@+id/userEmail"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

                />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_white"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock_outline"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/userPassword"
            />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:hint="Confirm Password"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_white"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock_outline"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:id="@+id/userConfirmPassword"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="REGISTER"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:background="@drawable/register_button"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                />
<TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""

                android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
                />


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly ! I just needed to change a small thing and thats working as I want to. I just feel bad about the hacking thing, I'm new to Android comming from web develop, I was so excited about it but you need so much efforts to do small things... Thank you Amam!!!

Comment: Yeah, I have been working on Android for quite a while and it got issues. Welcome to Android. And one little advice according to UX, if user clicks on Edit text you should hide that HQSM logo and unhide when keyboard is gone. Since the user is entering his/her details its unwise to show that. Just an Advice for better UI and UX.

Comment: Thank you again ! That should be easy. Really thank you, man!

Comment: Actually I found a problem. Now, with the new hack, when I try to scroll down. It scrolls all the way down and there is a blank space (because of the new element hack). Any ideia??

Comment: That is the only problem with this hack. But it will not affect the performance or anything. You could do one thing, you can set the visibility of the newTextView in oncreate to GONE and when ever user click on edit text or Keyboard is shown then you can set the visibility to VISIBLE and it will scroll.

Comment: It is now advised by Android to set the Edittext at the bottom of the Screen. Like I said earlier you can hide the HSQM logo and that way you have more space and you might not have to scroll down. Optimise your Layout if you don't want to use the hack. However, it is not that bad as it seems.